# "Multiple active partitions" error

Tags: windows-7, live-usb, installation

I already have Ubuntu 11.04 (which I installed with WUBI) and Windows 7.

I also want to install Ubuntu 11.10 Beta.

When I boot with the Ubuntu USB, I get the error: `Multiple active partitions`.

Then, I get redirected to the boot options.

I think I should also mention that a `wubi.exe` file is automatically created, although I mounted within Ubuntu.

Answer (score 1):

Write the image with the *last* version of Ultra ISO.

I had this problem with every Ubuntu release.

Unetbootin didn't help, only the latest versions of Ultra ISO at the moment.